# In SSRS how to make a net Revenue out two total columns in table

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have a table in SSRS that show all sources I have revenue from but I need to have net revenue based on a total column and the concessions column. I am fairly new to SSRS and not good at expressions calculations.

Revenue screenshot:

[image: Revenue Picture]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A pic of the table in Design view with the Grouping on the left would help, along with the Total expression. Are the concession amounts in the same dataset and they're being excluded from the Total or are they from another dataset?